# Variable not being displayed in DOM, yet ng-repeat works

Tags: angularjs, django-templates, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I was setting up a very basic AngularJS + Ionic app, and encountered a weird case where despite the ng-repeat working properly (e.g repeating the correct number of times), the variables weren't rendered on the DOM. Additionally, I saw this weird behavior only happening in my local app, but working properly on an exact copy on Plunker.

On `app.js` I have:

```
angular.module('sleepExpertChatApp', [
  'ionic',
])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('peoplelist', {
    url: '/peoplelist',
    templateUrl: 'templates/people-list.html',
    controller: 'PeopleListCtrl'
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/peoplelist');
})

.controller('PeopleListCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.obj = {}
    $scope.test = "Mytestvar"
    $scope.obj.people = [{name:"leon"},{name:"jeff"},{name:"leon"}];
    console.log($scope.obj);
});
```

And my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="sleepExpertChatApp">
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/chat/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    <script id="templates/people-list.html" type="text/ng-template">
        <ion-view id="userMessagesView"
          view-title="People">
          afsdf
          <ion-content>
                <div ng-repeat="person in obj.people">
                    <div class="item">
                        {{person.name}}
                    </div>
                </div>
        </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/UV3AJoEFpUeE45DkVv9A

Locally, the simple ng-repeat does produce the right number of elements, but when trying to evaluate the expression to display the variables, nothing is shown. See the below screenshot and notice that there are 3 divs with class `item`, as expected, but they have no name.

Any ideas what could be going wrong in this seemingly trivial set up?

[image: DOM of my problem]

Comment: Are you running your local copy on a server? Because this is necessary for angular to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Ah! I didn't realize I was serving the HTML from a Django server, and so Django's template rendering engine was clashing with AngularJS's.

Simply wrapping my HTML with Django's `{% verbatim %}` tag fixed my problem.